# 特定のメンバが他クラスで使用されている箇所を一覧にして表示したい。

Tags: c#

IDEでよくある「Find Usages.」のような、特定の関数などが使用された箇所を一覧にして、コンソールに出力したいと考えています。
すでにライブラリやツールがあるのであれば、お教えいただきたいのですが、なければ、こういうふうに実装したら？などの助言をいただけますと幸いです。

自作する場合、できればC#のみで完結して実装したいと考えていますが、pythonやその他言語で実装が可能でしたらお教えいただきたく思います！

Comment: 質問は後からでも [編集] できるので、本文に直接追記してみてください。 / 蛇足になりますが、ユーザー名の綴りは "beginner" が正しいものだと思います (意図して設定しているようでしたらすみません)。

Answer (score 1):

VisualStudio2019であれば、コード上の関数名を右クリックして「すべての参照を検索(A)」で表示されます。
結果をテキストで保存したい場合は結果の表示されてるパネルのメニューバーの「リストビュー(L)」をクリックすれば一覧をコピーできるようになります。